# mongodb lookup need to connect with user model

Tags: mongodb, join, lookup

country collection

```
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'country_name1',
}
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'country_name2',
}
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'country_name3',
}
```

state collection

```
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'state_name1',
'country_id':'country_id_1'
},
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'state_name2',
'country_id':'country_id_1'
},
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'state_name3',
'country_id':'country_id_2'
}
```

city collection

```
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'city_name1',
'state_id':'state_id_1'
},
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'city_name2',
'state_id':'state_id_1'
},
{
'_id':'mongodb_id',
name:'city_name3',
'state':'country_id_2'
}
```

Here I want to join the country, state and city with user collection
user

```
{
'_id':'mongo_id',
'name':'xyz',
'city':'cityid_2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate the users collection, with any limiting matches first, then:

- $lookup in the city collection, using localField "city" and foreignField "_id"
  This should return an array of matching cities, which should be 1 element in length
- $lookup in the state collection, using localField "cityResults.state", foreignField "_id"
- $lookup in the country collection, using localField "stateResults.country", foreignField "_id"
- $project to form the results into the desired shape.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the User Scehma like:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   name: { type: String },
   cityID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City' } // 'City' is the name you've to the city model while exporting the module.
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Now in the controller, populate the cityID like

```
User.findById(<userID>)
  .populate('cityID')
  .then(user => res.status(200).send(user))
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time answering my question. I'm using loopback 3 so I want to resolve using MongoDB (aggregate) functions